# How to generate new guid for each installed instance?

Tags: c#, .net, guid

I use C#. Is it possible to make every installed instance has different guid?

To be more specific, let's say I have an application called "abc" and a setup for it. Each time it is installed on a different computer, I want it's assembly guid to be regenerated. If it's not possible, I always listen to new ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need this? What's the benefit over say an entry in the configuration file?

Comment: I don't want it to be editable. Basically I need a product id.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? It is unclear.

Comment: While the GUID has enough possible combinations to be considered "unique" there is no guarantee. A GUID has a product identification is not going to work.  The only real way to do this is to generate a list of valid product ids, and use user input, or use a physical device I suppose.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think the possibility of a GUID collision is anything to worry about..

Comment: @MattDavey - A GUID still is not an acceptable product identification code.  The major reason there is no way to verify the GUID generate would be valid.  I would also like to add that the user wants the GUID of the assembly to be changed after it was compiled which doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: @Ramhound I agree GUID is not the best option for a product id - anyone can generate a valid GUID

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check for a file on startup ?  You could then Generate a UID and insert it into the file. So the next time the Application loads you would be able to read the UID from the file ?

This could be either on a per user basis (where you would put the file in their user directory) or per installation (Where the file is right next to the executable or somewhere outside of the current user directory, just watch out for Windows File Permissions!).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to uniquely identify the machine on which your application is installed. There are many ways to do this - but changing the assembly GUID is not a good option for this.

Instead, you should look at the machine configuration, and generate a unique Id from it rather than generating a random id. For example, you could take the machines [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) as a starting point.

This would make the machines unique id **deterministic**, meaning you don't need to store it anywhere, you can generate it each time you need it :)

Early versions of the GUID specification (version 1) actually used the machines MAC address as part of the GUID - however this led to security problems and was the cause of the [Melissa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melissa_%28computer_virus%29) virus. The modern GUID specification does not use MAC address data.